# Swift - How to remove a button created in a function?

Tags: ios, xcode, button, removechild

I have created a simple function which checks for a certain condition. If that is the case it calls another function which created a button programmatically, which randomly shows an image (plus dies something else).

Before the button is created I'd like to check if the button already exists and delete it so that a new random one is created. 
Another used case could be to check in the first function if the button already exists and just delete it.

Whatever I do Xcode says I try to use the variable before it is declared (which is logical, but I don't know how to change this).

```
func check() {
    if condition is met {
        createButton()
    }
}

funk createButton()
    let number = arc4random_uniform(3)

        let multiButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "multi\(number)")
        multiButton.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width / 5, height: frame.size.width / 5)
        multiButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY + colorSwitch.size.height)
        multiButton.name = "multiButton"
        multiButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        addChild(multiButton)
}
```

Now as I wrote I'd like to check in the first function createButton() if the button already exists and if so just delete it or instead in the second function before the button is created if it already exists and again delete it so that a new one can be created.

I tried to use:

```
multiButton.removeFromParent()
```

But this doesn't work because I try to access the variable before it is created.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `button` (or whatever you want to call it) property to your class. When you create a button, assign it to the property, and the next time you need to create one, first call `button.removeFromSuperview()`, then reassign a new button to it.

That's *how* to solve it, but it doesn't address *why* you're doing it this way. Why not just have a property that only ever points to a single instance of the button, and instead of removing and creating buttons, just change the button's title, action, and/or other button properties.

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more info or under what keywords I can search for this exactly? I am still learning and sometimes it's quite difficult.